# Django template doesn't seem to be getting my context dictionary

Tags: django, django-templates, django-context

The following template renders with the image from the static directory appearing, but `myvar` doesn't show up. Somehow `{{STATIC_URL}}` is being evaluated correctly, but `{{myvar}}` is empty. What am I missing?

views.py

```
def home(request):
    return render_to_response('home/home.html', 
        {
        'myvar':"something",
        },
        context_instance=RequestContext(request,{}))
```

home.html

```
<html>
<h1>{{myvar}}</h1>

<img src="{{STATIC_URL}}home/Marcy.jpg">
</html>
```

Comment: Does replacing `context_instance=RequestContext(request,{})` with `context_instance=RequestContext(request)` help?

Comment: Or just `render(request, 'home/home.html', {'myvar': 'something'})`.

Comment: Neither of these work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Was missing something obvious: Error was being thrown when restarting gunicorn. Once fixed, problem went away.

Answer (score 0):

On official documentation of Django 1.7, on [render_to_response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#id2) method, the example uses `context_instance=RequestContext(request)`. So, if you take it off the dict of RequestContext, maybe this works.